# melamine paint onto plywood - blotchy

Tags: plywood

I appear to be unable to get an even matt finish despite giving the plywood two coats and allowing for 24hrs to dry before applying another.

Problem is it appears to be blotchy in certain areas why?

The reason I choose this melamine paint was so I can wipe it down if I need to.

Comment: What kind of plywood are you using? There are different "grades", and in general over the years I have found quite a bit of variation in the smoothness of the surface, which can affect painting quite a bit.

Comment: Did you use a good primer on plywood allow to dry and sand before applying the finish coats?

Comment: Ok so I must use a good primer allow to dry and sand? I am not sure of the grade but I got it for 26 quid 8x4 ft 18mm sheet probably BB grade only.

Comment: so if I wanted to start again, can I just sand all the paint off to bare wood then primer

Comment: Perhaps you could take a picture of the wood to further help providing the best answer.  I prepared my stairs using wood filler before priming and painting with melamine paint. Of course sanding at each stage before the final coat.